# passwordless authentication with SSH key pair

Tags: centos, ssh

Apologies if this question isn't sophisticated enough, I am sort of new to Gnu/Linux. I've 4 VMs in Azure all running CentOS, 1 master and 3 workers.

I've set up a passwordless authentication between these using ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id commands and added hostnames with respective IP addresses into the `/etc/hosts` file. Everything works OK. However if I log into the master not from my work laptop, but from my home machine (using putty), with the same user I cannot do `ssh worker1` anymore, I get permission denied (public_key) and I don't understand why it is, as this was set between the hosts, why does it matter where I'm logging in from. Can anyone explain please?

Comment: Can you run the `@` form on both?: `ssh -vvv user@machine`, and run `ssh-add -l` on both machines. Edit question to show the output of both commands. Have you added the public key of your home machine to the servers?

Comment: It the master called `worker1`?

Comment: There is a master and worker1, worker2 and worker3. So i can log into the master from my home machine using the username and password, but i cannot do ssh worker1 or ssh worker2 anymore, it works if i log in from the same machine which i've used to set up the authentication from but not from another machine. In principle is it a normal behavior? Is there some MAC address stamp or anything like that...?

Comment: Oh that is not what you said in the question. Can you update the question.

Comment: There is a master and worker1, worker2 and worker3. No i haven't added public key of my home machine, but i've added a public key of an 'admin' user on master to all 3 workers so i expect it should work no matter which host i login from. I can log into the master from my home machine using the username and password, but i cannot do ssh worker1 or ssh worker2 anymore, it works if i log in from the same machine which i've used to set up the authentication from but not from another machine. In principle is it a normal behavior? Is there some MAC address stamp or anything like that...?

Comment: Can you update the question?

Answer (score 0):

You probably uploaded a wrong public key to the worker machines. Check the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on workers and make sure it matches the public key (probably `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) on the master node.